# TYPO3 v4.6 Questions about RealUrl (nomatch for lookuptable)

Tags: content-management-system, typo3, realurl

You must get a reference to the type:
`http://site.ru/agencies/town/name_agencies.`

Here is an example of code that is at the moment:

```
'fixedPostVars' => array(
    '71' => array (
        array (
            'GETvar' => 'tx_extention_pi1[town_id]',
            'lookUpTable' => array(
                'table' => 'tx_extention_table',
                'id_field' => 'uid',
                'alias_field' => 'town_name',
                'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                    'strtolower' => 1,
                    'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                    ),
                ),

            ),
        array (
            'GETvar' => 'tx_extention_pi1[uid]',
            'lookUpTable' => array(
                'table' => 'tx_extention_table2',
                'id_field' => 'uid',
                'alias_field' => 'IFNULL(NULLIF(pathsegment,""), agency_title)',
                'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                    'strtolower' => 1,
                    'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                    ),
                ),

            ),
        ), 
),
```

The result of his work is correct, but taking into account the fact that `town_id` always determined.

If `town_id` not established a link have the form:

`site.ru/agencies//name_agencies`

And the need for such a case:

`site.ru/agencies/name_agencies`

Use `'noMatch' => 'bypass'` makes no sense, since it is intended to `'valueMap' => array ()`. A `'valueDefault' => 'string'` only specifies the default option, unless otherwise provided.

Is there any option that is designed to `'lookUpTable' => array ()`, but to work as a `'noMatch' => 'bypass'`?

I.e. to move to the next segment if the current is not defined.

Comment: TYPO3 4.6 is out of support for years. Please upgrade to a currently supported version of TYPO3 and realurl. Have you tried to create a second set of fixed post vars with just the second configuration?

Comment: The task set for version 4.6.
What is the second set? You mean - `post var sets`? Or what?
Sorry, my English is bad.